# Jenkins notifyCommit trigger not working?

Tags: svn, jenkins

I've been working with this issue for a couple of hours now and it seems I'm doing something wrong.

First, svn's post-commit hook is already working since I'm already able to see a log, here is the code for post-commit:

```
#!/bin/sh

REPOS="$1"
REV="$2"
UUID=`svnlook uuid $REPOS`

/bin/echo "$REPOS $REV $UUID" >> /var/subversion/svn-post-commit.out
```

Note that for it to work you need to execute chmod 777 to post-commit and execute chown www-data:www-data to the svn repository.

What didn't work is the jenkins notifyCommit, that would auto build the project in jenkins:

```
/usr/bin/wget \
  --header "Content-Type:text/plain;charset=UTF-8" \
  --post-data "'svnlook changed --revision $REV $REPOS'" \
  --output-document "-" \
  --timeout=2 \
  http://localhost:8080/subversion/${UUID}/notifyCommit?rev=$REV
```

I also tried invoking via curl

```
curl --data "rev=4" http://localhost:8080/subversion/c8bb87ec-9a19-4975-ab9d-8b15741e6d7e/notifyCommit
```

No error but jenkins did not build.

Any ideas?

curl's reply:

```
* About to connect() to 10.1.1.133 port 8080 (#0)
*   Trying 10.1.1.133... connected
> POST /subversion/c8bb87ec-9a19-4975-ab9d-8b15741e6d7e/notifyCommit HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.22.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1 zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3
> Host: 10.1.1.133:8080
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 5
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> 
* upload completely sent off: 5out of 5 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: Winstone Servlet Engine v0.9.10
< Connection: Close
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
< Date: Mon, 22 Oct 2012 05:48:49 GMT
< X-Powered-By: Servlet/2.5 (Winstone/0.9.10)
< 
* Closing connection #0
```

Thanks,

czetsuya

Comment: try adding -v to your curl command to see what the headers in the response say. Also does your jenkins have a username:password? If so you can try adding that in your curl request http://username:password@localhost:8080/......

Comment: Hi Baldur, I've attached the curl's response above. I've also tried with username and password - same response but still jenkins did not start the build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a work around but it's not elegant. I've used jenkins cli to invoke the build manually. I've documented what I did here:

http://czetsuya-tech.blogspot.com/2012/10/an-alternative-way-of-invoking-jenkins.html.

Comment: Like the answer from David W, this is a great solution but it doesn't address the original question of how to get notifyCommit working. This solution requires the commit hook know the actual job name, which makes it a lot more complex than sending the global commit notify to Jenkins.

Answer (score 6):

There are two methods for starting a build remotely in Jenkins, that I have used successfully. (The examples are for a shell script)

One is by using the URL and start a PARTICULAR JOB:

**Method 1:**

```
WGET="/usr/bin/wget"
JENKINS_JOB="Your-Job-Name"
$WGET http://ip:port/job/$JENKINS_JOB/build?token=sampletocken
```

If you're trying to start a job that's parameterized, you can specify the parameters this way (otherwise the job will not start):

```
$WGET http://ip:port/job/$JENKINS_JOB/buildWithParameters?param-name=param-value&token=sampletocken
```

The part with the token=sampletocken is not required, but adds a little security. You can configure the token in your Job configuration under "Trigger builds remotely".

The other method is by using the Jenkins subversion API:

**Method 2:**

```
# REPOS is the local path of the repository.
# REV is the revision that we want to build.
# SERVER is the full URL of Jenkins.
# UUID of the repository (it will be used to identify it to Jenkins)

REPOS="$1"
REV="$2"
SERVER="http://ip:port"
UUID=`svnlook uuid $REPOS`

$WGET \
  --header "Content-Type:text/plain;charset=UTF-8" \
  --post-data "`svnlook changed --revision $REV $REPOS`" \
  --output-document "-" \
  --timeout=2 \
  $SERVER/subversion/${UUID}/notifyCommit?rev=$REV
```

For this all to work, you must have given proper rights to the anonymous user in Jenkins. However, this might be something you don't want to do, as it raises security concerns.

**Authentication**

In order to make it more secure, you can create a separate user that will be used in the script to authenticate to Jenkins. Configure this user to have some "API Token" that you're going to use in the script. (don't forget to remove all rights for the Anonymous user)

Then you need to add the following to your wget command:

```
wget --auth-no-challenge --http-user=user --http-password=apiToken
```

The "--auth-no-challenge" is used to avoid "403 forbidden" error.
You can also add the other token to the URL, as in the previous example.

This last part proved to be problematic for me, so it could take some trial and error...

Answer (score 2):

When you want to fire off Jenkins builds remotely, you have to select *Trigger builds remotely (e.g., from scripts)* in the *Build Triggers* section of the job. When you do that, you give it a token that has to be passed to the Jenkins project.

For example, if your build token is `BUILD`, you would pass

```
http://<JenkinsURL>/job/<jobName>/build?token=BUILD
```

I did this a lot with CVS because CVS would take too long and require too many resources for Jenkins to see if there had been a commit. CVS had to go through every file in the project to see if there was an update. I don't usually do this with Subversion because Subversion can instantaneously see whether or not there has been a change in the repository and that check takes very little resources.

Comment: This is correct, but you are describing an alternative method to start a build. The original question is about the method through the subversion plugin API, so to say (using UUID instead of Job name).